# How do I resolve these errors when I import my SDQ file?

Tags: mysql, database

When I'm importing my SQL file, these errors occurred. Please help me with it.
[image]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

On the last line afer `'subject_id' varchar(255)NOT NULL, ...`  need to be   `... , 'subject_id' varchar(255)NOT NULL,'up_vote' int ) ENGINE=InnoDB`

Comment: Thank you so much mate.really appriciated